# Import Data do not keep Identity Column auto insert in destination table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I m using Import data wizard (right clicking on destination db > Tasks > Import Data) to import data and schema from source to destination db. On finishing wizard I can see database tables with data are copied but somehow Import Wizard do not keep identity insert auto increment on table.

I tried 'Edit Mappings > Enable Identity Insert' but still result is same. Unfortunately this result is incorrect. Kindly guide how I can make it working correct i.e. setting Identity column auto insert. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the syntax too `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON`

Comment: @sqluser how to do that ? Is it a option I will have in Import wizard ? Please guide. If you are saying I should do it in table > design then yes I tried but I cant do it because table has data that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the default behavior. To override, follow these steps -

After selecting the source and destination tables, click on edit mappings. In the resultant pop-up, click on edit SQL and edit the auto-generated SQL and add `IDENTITY (1,1)` at the end of the column you want to set `IDENTITY` property. Ensure that you have enabled `IDENTITY INSERT ON` by checking the relevant box.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Was a little bit of effort, but much better than dropping/recreating a bunch of tables.